# a4j:poll timer reset

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm using a4j:poll to call an actionListener every X seconds (configurable in the backing bean). However if I reload the page the timer resets, is there any way to prevent this?

```
Example:   I set the interval to 30000 (30 seconds)
Second 0:  The page is loaded for the first time
Second 15: I reload the page, by pressing F5 or by clicking on a link to the same page
Second 30: I expect the actionListener to be called but nothing happens
Second 45: The actionListener finally gets called, exactly 30 seconds after the reload
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say no. Partial reloading from within ajax does not reset the timer but reloading the whole page restarts all javascript and so all pollers.

You could use 'push' to do backend triggering instead of polling. The backend could use a servlet that just fires every 30 seconds independent on what the user does on the frontend. With RichFaces 4.2 the push is extremely easy to implement.

MAG,
Milo van der Zee